# Qulice - How to disable rule that requires package-info.java on the entire project?

Tags: java, qulice

I've setup my `pom.xml` to use Qulice:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.qulice</groupId>
            <artifactId>qulice-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <license>file:${basedir}/LICENSE.txt</license>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I've added some initial files and ran `mvn clean install`, then Qulice complains:

> [INFO] Checkstyle: src/main/java/hk/com/novare/App.java[0]: Missing package-info.java file. (JavadocPackageCheck)
>
> [INFO] Checkstyle: src/main/java/hk/com/novare/App.java[2]: Line does not match expected header line of ' */'. (HeaderCheck)
>
> [INFO] Checkstyle: src/main/java/hk/com/novare/App.java[28]: Missing '@since' tag in class/interface comment (JavadocTagsCheck)

There is a way to exclude certain *files* from Qulice, as documented [here](https://www.qulice.com/qulice-maven-plugin/example-exclude.html), but is there a way to exclude a certain *rule* from the entire project, such as Checkstyle's **JavadocPackageCheck** rule ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://github.com/teamed/qulice/issues/507#issuecomment-162519518 As of `Dec 7, 2015` It's apparently a 'feature' of qulice the inability to further customize the best practices they ship, and they do not provide a way to disable rules barring the inherent annotations shipped with each of the tools that it comprises.

Their recommendation would likely to be to use the individual tools yourself, with your own configuration if you wish to.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer. If that is the case then I have to configure the tools individually.

Answer (score 0):

##### Sometimes you just *need* to do this in real practice.

There is a way using `@checkstyle <RuleName> (<N> lines)` comment and `@SuppressWarnings("PMD.<RuleName>")` code annotations, see [the Qulice's site page](https://www.qulice.com/quality.html).

This works with latest Qulice maven plugin `(0.18.19)`, just place it above line the error points at.